# How to view request performance in Application Insights regardless of URL path parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights to monitor my APIs. When viewing the performance of my endpoints, AI seems to split requests based on their path, including any path parameters. This is not helpful to me; I would like to investigate performance (and get performance alerts) for e.g. all `PATCH /observations/{id}` operations when viewed together, not when viewed individually for each `{id}`.

Put another way, in the screenshot below, I would like the underlined operations to all be in the same row, e.g. `PATCH /observations/{id}`.

[image: screenshot]

Is this possible without a lot of boilerplate code, and without ruining other monitoring features (which editing the telemetry operation names might, though I may be wrong)?

I am using ASP.NET Core endpoint routing, so the framework has all necessary information about the routing (tokens etc.).

Grouping requests this way for performance monitoring seems so obvious that I am surprised that it is so hard to figure this out, or that there are seemingly no "canonical" and simple way to accomplish this. Please let me know if I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Seems this has been raised as an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1418

Comment: I don't have this issue. Have you tried to use `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` NuGet package? Don't forget to initialize it through `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()`

Comment: I am doing that. As mentioned in the previous comment, this is an open issue on the official AI repo. So this is a real issue. One of the commenters on that issue (the most recent comment at the time of writing this) posted a workaround. If you don't experience it, perhaps you are using other code/libraries/frameworks that handle this for you, or perhaps you are setting up routes/endpoints differently.